# Issues looping through listview Android

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have some issues looping through all objects in a listview that uses my own custom adapterclass. The idea is that for each row where a checkbox is checked, something happens. Now, the function checkBoxCount correctly identifies the number of checked boxes and which position. However, when i check more than one box i get:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
```

The error occurs at the row where i assign the listitem to "f".

```
void checkBoxCount(){

    for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
        CheckBox cb = list.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSendAnytimerTo);

        if (cb.isChecked()){
            Log.d("i= ",String.valueOf(i));
            f = (Friend) list.getItemAtPosition(i);

        }

    }

}
```

This is my adapter because i feel like somethings going wrong there:

```
public class SendAnytimerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> {

    ArrayList<Friend> friendList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SendAnytimerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Friend> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        friendList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_anytimer_adapter_layout, null);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewSendAnytimerAdapterName);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewSendAnytimerAdapterCount);
        textView2.setText(friendList.get(position).getAnytimerCountFriend());
        textView1.setText(friendList.get(position).getfriendUserName());
        return v;
    }
```

Any clues on where my mistake lies?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there somewhere you remove all items in your list ?

Comment: @Override
public int getCount() {
    return friendList .size();
}

Comment: Damn, you are right. Time to visit my optician...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the method getCount

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return friendList.size();
}
```